# Why is ParseInt() returning NaN on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, parseint

Go to the console of Microsoft Edge and run the following JavaScript:

```js
current_date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-CA",{timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
a = current_date.substring(0,current_date.indexOf('-'));
console.log(parseInt(a));
```

I get a NaN; do you? I tried this same code in the console of Chrome and Firefox and they all yield "2019" when parseInt(a) is run.

1) Why is this happening?

2) How can I parse the "a" variable and convert it into an integer in Microsoft Edge?

[image: screenshot of console output]

Comment: When you do this, what is the value of `a`?

Comment: Why would you do this anyway? There are date methods. But debug what you have `console.log(current_date , a)`

Comment: Works fine in edge for me. -1 for making me open edge :)

Comment: Look at the value of `a` **before** you try to parse it as an integer.

Comment: Works fine here too: https://imgur.com/a/1vPi88C You'll need to provide the values returned in your intermediate calculations to progress any further.

Comment: My guess is this is nothing to do with edge and more to do with your configured timezone, which is likely different in different browsers. Needs an MCVE

Comment: @JoshWilson I get NaN in Edge, but I get 2019 in Chrome and Firefox. Why on earth would this be only happening to me, isn't console universal?

Comment: Why not just call `.getFullYear()` on the Date object?

Comment: @Quentin The value of "a" is "2019" in Edge, it's only when I run parseInt on it that this happens. Super bizarre.

Comment: `parseInt("2019")` is 100% going to work on **all** browsers. You're missing something

Comment: @Liam unless there's some Unicode weirdness with the string due to some locale issue.

Comment: The console isn't universal, IE/Edge uses a different JavaScript engine. In IE I get `10/07/2019` for `a`, which has no dash in it.

Comment: Well yes, I chose my words carefully there @Pointy

Comment: @Railsprogrammer94, I tested your code with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and it is working fine on my side. Here you can see the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/66fS7Gqp/184.png

Comment: can you `console.log(a, parseInt(a))`? executing `a = b;` on the console doesn't log the value of `a` but the value of `b`; that's a peculiarity of the `=` operator. So `a` might not have been (over)written?

Comment: @Thomas console.log(a,parseInt(a)) yields: 2019‎ NaN https://i.postimg.cc/W3Xw1qYs/Untitled.png

Comment: @Railsprogrammer94 OK, I have no idea how you manage to produce this result. The only thing that I would try is checking the string charCode by charcode to ensure that it doesn't just look like `2019` and that there are no weird invisible characters in there; even if I have no clue where they could come from. If the string still proves fine, then there's something wrong with your `parseInt`. Do you load anything that might overwrite it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the same issue when running the snippet in Edge.

Edge apparently adds some hidden formatting to the string when using `ToLocaleDateString()` so that has to be cleared before using either `parseInt()` or `Number()`  like `.replace(/\u200E/g, '');`

[Reference](https://formativeinnovations.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/ieedge-does-not-return-a-parsable-string-with-tolocaletimestring/)

```js
current_date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-CA",{timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}).replace(/\u200E/g, '');
a = current_date.substring(0,current_date.indexOf('-'));
console.log(parseInt(a));
console.log(Number(new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {day: "numeric"}).replace(/\u200E/g, '')));
```